# Ubuntu on Toshiba p50-12z with nvidia optimus

Tags: nvidia

Im trying boot Ubuntu on a Toshiba p50-12z, already disable secure boot and build-in LAN. When I boot Ubuntu and select "Try Ubuntu without install" or "install ubuntu" it freezes on startup splash(purple screen with dots...)

Maybe the reasons is my Nvidia GeForce GT 745M with CUDA and NVIDIA Optimus.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have searched for a solution to this problem, but I could not find anything on the web.

I have a Debian installation where my custom kernel wouldn't boot, but the stock kernel would with the LAN enabled. I noticed that the framebuffer would detect the native resolution with the LAN on and stay at a low resolution with it off.

I discovered that if you start booting with the simple framebuffer you can boot with the LAN on. The following are are the kernel config options that seems to "fix" the issue (for Kernel v3.14.2):

```
CONFIG_X86_SYSFB=y

\# CONFIG_DRM_NOUVEAU is not set

CONFIG_DRM_I915=y<br>
CONFIG_DRM_I915_KMS=y<br>
CONFIG_DRM_I915_FBDEV=y<br>

CONFIG_FB_SIMPLE=y<br>
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
```

Comment: Could you expand the answer to state, how and where to apply these config options. Moreover, would one need to compile the kernel for these to work?

Answer (score 0):

A user in the forums posted this:

Turned NIC (Integrated Network Interface Controller) off and then booted off of USB. Was NOT an issue with any Linux distro just a quirk of the laptop.
 Am now running 13.10 daily and everything works. Also had to stick with EFI boot ON, Secure Boot disabled. Wouldn't boot off of any media or HDD when mode set to CSM.

Toshiba Satellite P50 model number: P50-A-01E Haswell processor

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163854

Comment: I disable build-in lan(cant find NIC)...before that it gave me a black screen, did not reach the splashscreen.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding "nomodeset" to your linux boot.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While your answer might solve the problem, you should include the essential parts from the linked page.[Why is linking bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad).

Comment: Already try "nomodeset", the result is the same

Comment: I know this sounds crazy but have you try unplugging the hard drive? Then booting Ubuntu into Live mode. I had to do this for one laptop which was Toshiba P75. I unplugged it, then booted into Ubuntu Live, then plugged the hard drive back in while it was on. Then installed Ubuntu on the hard drive.